# Fish: for loop: Too many args for cd command

Tags: for-loop, fish, cd

If I run a script

```
#!/usr/bin/fish
cd /home/user/repos/repo1
pwd
```

works as intended (changes directory and prints that path).

When I place the same logic into a for loop, `cd` complains about too many arguments even though there are no space and .

```sh
#! /usr/bin/fish

set REPOS "/home/user/repos/repo1" "/home/user/repos/repo1"

for REPO_PATH in $REPOS:
    echo $REPO_PATH
    cd $REPO_PATH
    pwd
end
```

Using relative paths doesn't help,

```sh
set REPOS "~/repos/repo1" "~/repos/repo1"
```

using variables without quotes work outside for loop, same complaint inside for loop.

Works in bash like this

```sh
#!/bin/bash
repos=("/home/user/repos/repo1" "/home/user/repos/repo1")
for path in "${repos[@]}"
do
    cd $path
    pwd
done
```

I've read List and Loops section of fish documentation.
I've noticed that cd has a fish-wrapper. Could that be the issue?

Comment: The `:` is incorrect, and should be removed; it appends a `:` to each directory name. That doesn't seem to be related to the error you are reporting, though.

Comment: Insufficient data. For one thing you didn't actually show us the output of running your script. Also, as @chepner pointed out the trailing colon on the `for` statement is wrong -- it will cause each directory to have a colon appended to it. You should also replace the `echo $REPO_PATH` with `set --show REPO_PATH` to make any ambiguities regarding how many values the var holds clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the colon.

The reason this shows the error "Too many arguments" is that calling a variable "...PATH" causes fish to interpret it as a path variable, which means that it will be split on ":" (like $PATH, $LD_LIBRARY_PATH etc).

So fish goes, sets $REPO_PATH to "/home/user/repos/repo1:", then splits it on the ":", making it a list of "/home/user/repos/repo1" and "".

That's then passed to `cd` as two arguments, one being empty, and `cd` complains about having a second spurious argument.

So just use

```
set REPOS "/home/user/repos/repo1" "/home/user/repos/repo1"

for REPO_PATH in $REPOS
    echo $REPO_PATH
    cd $REPO_PATH
    pwd
end
```

Comment: But then why would `echo $REPO_PATH` not print both? I can see only the repo variable and not the colon.

Comment: Oh, I see because it was empty
```$REPO_PATH: set in local scope, unexported, with 2 elements
$REPO_PATH[1]: length=38 value=|/home/user/repos/repo1|
$REPO_PATH[2]: length=0 value=||
$REPO_PATH: not set in global scope
$REPO_PATH: not set in universal scope

Too many args for cd command```